# How to copy a HTML Web page into a new HTML email in Gmail so the images are included?

Tags: email, gmail, html

How to copy a HTML Web page into a new HTML email in Gmail so the images are included?  I.e. I don't want the email contains images only via links to the Web as I suspect some receipt will not be able to access the those images online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy and paste behaviour depends on the browser you're using - e.g. if you use chrome and copy and paste the images are inserted as images.

Comment: Nope, they aren't on mine.

Answer (score 2):

In order for Gmail to allow images inline with the message (not as attachments) you have to enable it in the settings.  Go to  **Settings**, select **Labs** at the top, and find **Inserting images** and change it to Enabled.  Once you've done this, Gmail will allow pictures to be displayed within the email, much like a webpage.  Whether or not they paste now will be based on how the website was formatted and how your browser handled the copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions:

1. Create your web mailer using table
2. Upload it to the server.
3. Open it in google chrome only
4. Select All or Ctrl+A
5. Copy or Ctrl+C
6. Paste into your mail editor/mail box
7. send...

done

Comment: Whhat does #1 and #2 actually mean? "table"? "web mailer"?

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that images are included in the E-mail and do not require visiting any websites by embedding them in the images used on the webpage (assuming that you made the webpage).

Check this article on just how you can do that:
http://blog.bigdinosaur.org/embedding-images-in-css/